# S is connected but int(S) is not

Tags: connectedness

I tried to have an example of a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $S$ is connected but int$(S)$ is not. Can anyone give me an example and prove it? Thanks

Comment: How about $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid xy\ge 0\}$? Or two disjoint discs joined by a line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT** : consider $S$ to be the union of two closed discs that touch at a point on their respective boundaries. This is connected but its interior is not.

Comment: How do you prove that $S$ is connected?

Comment: In this example, $S$ is path connected and hence connected. Can you say why there is always a path between any two points of $S$?

Comment: I can imagine that there is always a path between any two points of $S$. However, this question is designed for those people who don't know what path connected is. That's why I failed to prove $S$ is connected.